# Solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} - xy=1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} - xy=1$ given $y(0)=1$

The given differential equation is a first order linear differential equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx} + Py=Q$

The integrating factor is $$e^{\int Pdx}=e^{-\int xdx}=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Solution is $$ye^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx + c$$

But how do I integrate the second term?

Comment: Just call it the error function - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: it is $\int { { e }^{ -{ \frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ 2 }  } } } dx=\sqrt { \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  } erf\left( \frac { x }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \right) +C$

Comment: the solution is given by $$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to c_1 e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right\}\right\}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, you've solved the differential equation correctly.

---

The integral you are considering does not have an elementary antiderivative. Regardless, we can still obtain an exact solution in terms of the [error function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). The considered integral is:
$$\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}~dx$$
Now, substitute $$u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \implies du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}~dx\implies dx=\sqrt{2}~du$$ This gives an integral which is contained in the definition of the error function:
$$\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}~dx=\sqrt{2}\cdot \int e^{-u^2}~du$$
The definition of the error function is:

> $$\operatorname*{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}~dt$$

It follows from the definition that:
$$\int e^{-u^2}~du=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\cdot \operatorname*{erf}(u)+C$$
Can you continue? From solving the integral, you can find the general solution to your ODE, and then find the solution where $y(0)=1$.